# how to design a power amplifier's layout in l-edit?

Tags: power, design, layout

i want to design a power amplifier in [Tanner L-Edit](http://www.tannereda.com/l-edit-pro).

I want to write code in the .ext file but I don't know what syntax or language the .ext file is expecting.  Is it spice? I couldn't find a good tutorial.

The second option is to use the Dev-Gen tool but it produced this error:

```
Device = Mosfet
Channe = N
Single Transistor Length = 1.00
Single Transistor Width = 22.00
Transistor Multiple Count = 22
Bulk Pattern = 0
Gate Finger Pattern = 0
Source/Drain Finger Pattern = 0
Generated by: Dev-Gen ver. 14.11
```

[image]

If I check the SPICE paramter back annotation as in this screenshot:

[image]

All I get is the error (when I choose the .ext file `Generic_025.ext`)

> Extract definition file is not selected.
>   Please click Browse EXT File button to select the file.

[image]

Comment: We prefer error messages to be in text format.  That way, they're easier to read, and can be indexed by Google and by our search tools.  I transcribed the text in your first image, but that doesn't look like an error message to me.   Did you intend to write something different?

Comment: ok , thanks, no that is the error i get. and i assume that where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be going about things in a bit of an odd way, L-Edit is used for laying out IC's, from Tanner EDA you should really be using s-edit to design the schematic before laying out, as mistakes at the IC level can be very costly.

I believe that the .ext file is the extract definition file, the format for this is in the manual, it has been some time since I have looked at this.

Normally your silicon foundry will provide you with a process development kit which will include the design rules and extract definition. If not you will need to create this or get someone else to do this. I know tanner EDA and the European distributers EDA solutions provide this service but that costs money.

The Dev-gen function is only useful for creating individual devices such as capacitors and mosfets, to go from there you will need to create metal interconnects.

Comment: it has been a long time since i have used dev gen, I know there is a good section in the manual, which is available via the help menu